# How to pass parameters to android app on first open from install via link(not play store)

Tags: android

Say you have the following links on a page:

```
<a href=".../app-debug.apk">Download App</a>
<a href="my://app?id=123">Open App</a>
```

Then in the manifest(I know this is the hacky way of doing it):

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <data android:scheme="my" android:host="app" />
</intent-filter>
```

And finally, in the activity:

```
Uri data = getIntent().getData();
String id = data.getQueryParameter("id");
```

With this setup, the user has to click the download link, download the .apk, install it, go back to the page, and click the open link.

I wonder if there's a way to combine the download and open operations into one - perhaps pass the id parameter to the first link and somehow have it pass that on to the app.

I would like to do this without using the play store. (My issue with play store is this app is for a private group - but the group does not have Google accounts that could be used to distribute via play store private channel)

Comment: Exactly what I am searching for... And the only answer is "Duh, use the PlayStore anyway". Damn.

Answer (score 0):

You could still distribute it through the Play Store, to the specific people or group (not public) and then use the install referrer.

Read [this](http://help.webtrends.com/en/android/installation_referrals.html) and [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/tagmanager/InstallReferrerReceiver.html) .

The way you want to do it is impossible as far as I know. You're other alternative would be to just make the request from the background, without the user having to manually click the second link.

I guess it depends in what that data represents..

Comment: Is it possible to distribute to people who don't have google accounts? I would prefer to do this through Play Store, but this makes it sound like you can only distribute to your organization, where organization is a set of google-managed accounts - https://support.google.com/a/answer/2494992?hl=en

(I may have misunderstood - correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: It is possible to distribute only to a group, but they do need a Google account..

Comment: That's what I thought - unfortunately not all of the users have a google account.